# Filter by multiple years in DRF

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filter

So I'm trying to do filter by year and so it could use multiple values like this

```
filter?year=2000,2021
```

And with this I should get all objects with year 2000 or 2021

My filter.py

```
from django_filters import(
                            BaseInFilter,
                            NumberFilter,
                            FilterSet,
                            CharFilter,
    ) 
from .models import Research

class YearInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class ResarchFilter(FilterSet):
    year = YearInFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='year')
    category = CharFilter(field_name='category', lookup_expr='iexact')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Research
        fields = ['date', 'category']
```

It looks almost like example from django-filter.
But when I'm trying to use it i've got an error `Field 'None' expected a number but got [Decimal('2000'), Decimal('2021')].`

My views.py

```
class ResarchCategoryYear(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Research.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResearchSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ResarchFilter
```

So what's wrong here? Why here is Decimal? Why it's not number? And how make it work like expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data between this two year, use **range**
if you want only the data that is exists in those years, use **in**

example:

```
year = YearInFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='range')
year = YearInFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='in')
```

**Please** check how you can exactly apply those filters in Django_filter

edit:

you can make a custom search method in this way:

```
def custom_filter(self, queryset, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if not value:
        return queryset
    handleValue = value.split(',')
    queryset = YourModel.objects.filter(your_field__in=handleValue).distinct()
    return queryset
```

use it like this:

```
rest_framework.CharFilter(method=custom_filter)
```

and you can replace **CharFilter** based on what you want

Best of luck

Comment: withn lookup_expr='in' I'm getting an error like **fromisoformat: argument must be str**

Comment: Or if I change filter to DateFilter it works but only with exact days but I have dates in Model

Comment: I will edit my answer